# Basic IOS motion detectors

Tags: ios, accelerometer, motion-detection

Is there a framework or a library that covers the basic motions committed by the user
like moving the device up, down tossing the device, flipping etc.. based on the accelerometer
in iOS

Comment: enjoy:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

Core Motion framework will be the best choice.
You can find a nice tutorial here.

http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-19-using-core-motion-to-access-gyro-and-accelerometer/